# Linking to a complex number library in g++

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, makefile, g++

I am trying to get a C++ software, written to work with the xlC compiler, to work with g++. The Makefile of the original file has:

```
LIB = -lcomplex -L[address_to_user_folder] -lm
```

My concern is how to change the above line to work with g++ (I have already changed the compiler type in the first line: CC = g++. Also assuming no more changes are necessary.)

I tried this:

```
LIB = -lcomplex -lm
```

and received this error:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcomplex

I wonder if `-lcomplex` is valid in g++. If yes, why do I receive this error, and if not, how can I link to a complex number library in my Makefile?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just use `std::complex`?

Comment: What happens if you just remove -lcomplex from the definition of LIB?  Maybe g++ supports the complex features without requiring an external library.

Comment: If not, you have to compile that library with g++, then link it..

Comment: @OMGtechy : This might be an option, though, it actually makes me wonder why `-lm` should be used in the first place: Since the original C++ files include `<math.h>` library wherever necessary, then why should we link to the math library in the Makefile?

Comment: @Papillon `std::complex` is part of the `<complex>` header, so if you can include that then you'd be sorted :)

Comment: @JimLewis : I removed it and the compilation didn't produce any errors. Since this is a large project, I have to check many things to make sure if all is alright. I searched the web to realize if g++ supports complex numbers without requiring an external library. But I haven't found a concrete answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean "if g++ supports complex numbers"?

G++ supports the standard C++ type `std::complex` defined in the `<complex>` header, and also [C99-style complex numbers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Complex.html) (which are not part of standard C++, this is a GCC extension).

No external library is needed for these features.

If your software is using some other kind of complex numbers then maybe you need an external library.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification Jonathan! Considering that the software I am using has `#include <math.h>` wherever necessary, is it necessary to include `LIB = -lm` in my Makefile (since it links to the math library)?

Comment: No, gcc will add that if needed.